# Excluding records based upon a one to many SQL join

Tags: sql, sql-server

How would I write a SQL query that excludes a record if one (external) record from a one to many join matches a certain condition?

For example:

```
Details
ID      
1         
2         

Items
DetailID    Item
1           A
1           B
2           B
2           C
```

How would I select the detail records where the Items do not include 'A'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT *
FROM details d
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( 
  SELECT * 
  FROM items i
  WHERE i.DetailID == d.ID 
    AND i.Item = 'A')
```

Answer (score 2):

building on systempuntoout's solution:

```
SELECT details.*
FROM details 
LEFT OUTER JOIN items ON details.ID=items.DetailID AND items.Item = 'A'
WHERE items.DetailID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not just using INNER JOIN like:

```
SELECT details.*
FROM details 
INNER JOIN items ON details.ID=items.DetailID AND items.Item<> 'A'
```

Comment: That would return the second row in the items table. The OP wants to exclude detailId = 1 completely.

Comment: Is it that clear that OP wants it :)?Probably it's like you said.